# How to search in a ListView in Titanium Alloy by filtering only according to the first letter in the word?

Tags: android, ios, listview, titanium-alloy, searchbar

I am using Titanium Alloy and I have a searchBar that searches in my ListView which works fine, but if my list contains a word for example like "Adam" and I typed in the searchBar "m" the list will be filtered to any word that contains the letter "m" in it so "Adam" will show up although it starts with "A" not "m", so how do I solve this problem ?

Comment: can you show us code... and what data you used to populate your `ListView` from arrays or from database...

Comment: I get the contacts from the phonebook and put them into an array then populate the ListView with the names of contacts in this array then I set the searchText of this list to the text in my searchBar like this:
'$.search.addEventListener('change', function(e){
     $.list_allContacts.searchText = e.value;
 });'

Answer (score 5):

You can use "searchableText" to be able to search.And bydefault it will start searching from the first character of input. If you resrtict your searchText to 1 character length.They you will have a single character searching.For more follow this link http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/ListViews-section-37521650_ListViews-SearchTextandView

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({backgroundColor: 'white', fullscreen: true});
var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
 barColor:'#000', 
 showCancel:true,
 height:43,
 top:0,
});
search.addEventListener('cancel', function(){
    search.blur();
});
// for textSearch, use the change event to update the search value
// search.addEventListener('change', function(e){
//     listView.searchText = e.value;
// });
var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({searchView: search, caseInsensitiveSearch: true});
// for textSearch, add the search bar or text field as a header view
// var listView = Ti.UI.createListView({headerView: search, caseInsensitiveSearch: true});
var listSection = Ti.UI.createListSection();
var fruits = ['Papaya', 'Peach', 'Pear', 'Persimmon', 'Pineapple', 'Pluot', 'Pomegranate'];
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
data.push({
    properties: {title: fruits[i], searchableText: fruits[i]}
});
}
listSection.setItems(data);
listView.addEventListener('noresults', function(e){
    alert("No results found!");
});
listView.sections = [listSection];
win.add(listView);
win.open();
```